# Paint.createContext()

Tags: graphics, awt, java, swing

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("AAA");       GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().setFullScreenWindow(frame);

Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) frame.getGraphics();
Paint paint = graphics.getPaint();
PaintContext context = paint.createContext(ColorModel.getRGBdefault(),/*ВОТ здесь я застрял*/);
```

Не могу ему передать то, что он просит. По документации:

> ColorModel cm - the ColorModel that receives the Paint data. This is used only as a hint.
>
> Rectangle deviceBounds - the device space bounding box of the graphics primitive being rendered
>
> Rectangle2D userBounds - the user space bounding box of the graphics primitive being rendered
>
> AffineTransform xform - the AffineTransform from user space into device space
>
> RenderingHints hints - the hint that the context object uses to choose between rendering alternatives

С cm всё понятно. А вот с остальными... Вообщем, как правильно вызвать paint.createContext();